# Reservation System

Tags: ruby

Can anyone please tell me what I should be using and why this method isn't correct? The code doesn't work, I know, I just want to know how I can interface with the array for this type of thing.

Thank you.

Code:

```
$i = 1
$f = 0
$c = 0
answer = ""

loop do
    puts "Welcome\n"
    puts "If you'd like to fly in first class, Press 1. For coach, Push 2."
    answer = STDIN.gets
    answer.chop!
    break if answer =~ /1|2/  

    if answer == 1 then
      $i += 1.each
      $available.at(0..4)
    end

    if answer == 2 then
     $i += 1.each
     $available.at(5..19)

    else
      puts "Invalid number, enter 1 or 2."
      Console_Screen.pause
  end
end

puts "Here is your boarding pass. You are in seat " + $i.to_s
```

Comment: Maybe if the "airplane" tag was called "airplane mode", it'd be less likely to be used in questions like this.

Comment: `1.each` - this bit doesn't make sense to me. "each" is called on each value of something that can be iterated. 1 is just a FixNum -> it's not a set of things to be iterated over. So calling each on it makes no sense. I'm not sure what you're trying to do on that line at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first class, you can do something like this:

```
next_first = (0..4).find { |i| $available[i] != 1 }
```

If that gives you a `next_available` that is `nil` then first class is full, otherwise you have the index of the next available first class seat.

Similarly for coach:

```
next_coach = (5..19).find { |i| $available[i] != 1 }
```

Then once you have the index, have checked that it isn't `nil`, and stored it in `$i`, just `$available[$i] = 1` to reserve the seat.

And an extra hint for free, this:

```
answer = STDIN.gets
answer.chop!
```

leaves a string in `answer` so `answer == 1` will always be false.

References:

- [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short! So is my way valid? A few other students are doing it differently and thought my way is impossible.

Comment: @Redalin: [`Array#at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-at) wants a Fixnum, not a Range; and, 1 doesn't have an `each` method. Once you fix the "extra free hint" problem, you'll start hitting these errors.

Comment: I still cannot get the bloody questions to reference the array. @mu is too short, when the user inputs 1 or 2 what am I supposed to put? I keep trying to insert the choice into the boolean array, and add + 5 if the user wants to be in coach (since 1 - 5 are first class) but either it just puts the number I typed or doesn't show up

Comment: @Redalin: `(0..4).find { |i| $available[i] != 1 }` gives you the first available index in `$available` that is a 1st class seat, `(5..19).find { |i| $available[i] != 1 }` gives you the index for coach. And you'll want to use `answer == '1'` and `answer == '2'` to see what they entered.

Comment: So what I have above (using the ranges in array) is a correct way for this, @mu is too short? I also tried doing it by random number, but I had a creeping feeling that it would ultimately overwrite the boolean data since I'm unsure how I could keep track of what has been written.

Comment: @Redalin: No, `$available.at(0..4)` won't work because the `at` method wants a number but you're trying to give it a Range object. But you never get that far because `answer` will contain the strings `'1'` or `'2'` rather than the numbers `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here: 
`break if answer =~ /1|2/`
This means "stop and leave the loop entirely if if we get a 1 or 2"

ie it means that none of your code that does seat-allocation gets executed if the person actually enters something valid (ie a 1 or 2).

After that comes the errors pointed out by @mu_is_too_short above.